# Add event to XMLEventWriter

Tags: java, scala, xml-parsing

Does anyone knows any possible reason for the method add event to XMLEventWriter never return? After adding different events to XMLEventWriter, the add method never returns.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more details on what exactly you do with some code? Ideally create a [mcve] so we can see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened because I was not closing the event writter!